# Toolbar Does not show the overflow menu

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar

I've been following the Android Developers page on "Setting up the App Bar" linked [here](https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/setting-up.html). The problem is I can't seem to do it properly and the screen shows some weird toolbar with no overflow menu. I've read up on some other answers and to clarify, I am using Moto G2 for testing. It does not contain an Options button on the hardware side.

My Code is as follows:1. MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
}}
```

2. activity_main.xml

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.android.toolbardemo.MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

3. AndroidManifest.xml

```css
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.toolbardemo">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

The Android Developers page does not mention anything about creating a menu xml and stuff so I figure atleast the basic settings should appear.

Here is a picture of what I see:[No Overflow menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fKdl.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your `RelativeLayout` to this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.android.toolbardemo.MainActivity">
```

and you need to add this code to your activity

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.search_menu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Excellent! Thank you so much @Amir_P! I've spent about 2.5 hours on getting that overflow menu to work!

Comment: Thanks! The official developer guide is out-dated. It should be updated to add your `onCreateOptionsMenu(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your `toolbar` as `ActionBar` like this `setSupportActionBar(toolbar)` and override `onCreateOptionsMenu` in activity like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_search, menu);
    return true;
}
```

In your `menu.xml` file you need to set `app:showAsAction="never"`

```
<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:title="@string/search"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    app:showAsAction="never"/>
```